# Travelling to Himalayan National Park or Nanda Devi Reserve in Monsoon

Tags: india, weather-and-climate, national-parks, new-delhi

I will be arriving to New Delhi in 15th August and this is a rainy time in Delhi as well as certain other parts in northern India.

Is it safe to travel to any one of these two national parks in the Monsoon season? Are there any additional precautions which I should take while doing the same?

Comment: edited, apologies...

Comment: @MarkMayo Wouldn't it make sense to reopen the question since it seems *on-topic* and legitimate now? :/

Comment: @AdityaSomani if you click reopen, it will nominate it as such.  Then the community votes on it. It's not up to just me...

Comment: so should I wait, should I reopen...?

Comment: @Pixie What do you mean by safe to travel ? What are your major concerns regarding safety - is it getting raped, mugged, stabbed Or is it about avoiding Delhi Belly and other diseases Or are you asking about snakes or tigers that can leap out of the parks Or are you talking about pick pockets ? Or..There are other hundred things that could happen from your port of arrival in India till getting to the national parks

Comment: i meant basically physical danger yes. along with it, them being national parks, what is their level of organization i.e. are there designated routes etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Regarding Himalayan National Park**

The climate is typically the Western Himalayan temperate and alpine type. There are four distinct seasons recognized for GHNP: spring (April-June), rainy/summer (July-September), autumn (October-November) and winter (December-March).
During winter, the precipitation is in the form of snow even in lower elevation (1,560 m) and higher elevation areas experience heavy snowfall of over 2 m depth.

So I suggest that you avoid going there during winrer.

> Gears and Preparation

Trek Preparation

Periodic rest stops provide opportunities to appreciate the environment. It is essential to find the next overnight camping site well before the sunsets.   There are a few designated camping sites in high altitude pastures. Your local guide will be of help in selecting a place to camp, which is close to water and safe for the night rest.   Failure to set careful limits for oneself can result in tragedy. Know your limits–don’t endanger yourself or others!

Wear appropriate dress for each season and dress in layers for maximum comfort. Your trekking will be as comfortable as your boots. Make sure they are sturdy (with good ankle support and sturdy soles) and broken-in (new boots can often cause hot spots or blisters). Rain gear and sunscreen are essential. A warm hat, scarf, and gloves must also be part of your dress.

Additional clothing items should include:  
(1) down or insulated vest/jacket,
(2) rain-proof parka,
(3) socks and sock liners,
(4) sun hat,
(5) T-shirts,
(6) slippers or sandals for inside tent,
(7) thermal under-wear,
(8) sunglasses,
(9) down sleeping bag.

Other Items 
(1) adjustable walking stick,
(2) water bottle,
(3) high-grade water filter,
(4) Multi-blade knife.

Over-night stays have additional requirements, including, tents, sleeping bags, insulated mats, cooking utensils, food, etc. GHNP requires entry permits for treks. BTCA is a non-governmental group organized by local village people and provides full logistic trek support. BTCA offers guides, porters, tents, cooks, and coordinates different trek tours with GHNP staff.   If you are planning a multi-day trek to ensure you are properly equipped and informed.

> Travel Route

**Road Route**

From Delhi: Approximately 500 kms by road (14+ hour trip)

General route:
Delhi – Ambala (188 KM) – Chandigarh – Roopnagar (282 KM) – Kiratpur – Bilaspur (371 KM) – Mandi (440 KM) – Pandoh – Aut (481 KM) – Larji – Gushaini – Tirthan (511 KM)

Delhi to Chandigarh by National Highway 1, then to Aut in Mandi district by NH 21. The towns of Chandigarh and Swarghtat can be targeted to stay for staging the trip. Road journey in the mountain terrain of Himachal provides good views of Gobindsagar Lake near Bilaspur, followed by lush and wide Bahl Valley. The drive continues through the outskirts of Mandi which leads into the Pandoh gorge. After Pandoh comes the small town of Aut from where a link road goes across the bridge over Beas River into the Banjar valley, where the Park is located.

**Rail route:**

Chandigarh (296km) is the closest major Railway Station. From there you can either take a cab or bus.

Or if you would like to enjoy Toy Train ride, then you can come all the way up to Joginder Nagar(100 kms) (however only a few umber of trains are operated), in Mandi from Pathankot, and take a cab or bus from there.

Numerous trains run on Delhi to Pathankot route(broad gauge) and from there you change to the Toy train(narrow gauge). Its a long (about 10hrs) but beautiful journey to Joginder Nagar.

> Accommodation:

The National park has an ecozone with accommodation.

For additional Information on accommodation click [here](http://greathimalayannationalpark.com/accommodation/)

Comment: As mentioned above BTCA is a non-
governmental group
organized by local
village people and
provides full logistic
trek support.
It's is just like a local travel agency.