# Great Himalayan National Park in August: how are the roads?

Tags: weather-and-climate, national-parks, himalayas

I plan to travel Great Himalayan National Park (GHNP) in August by road (from Delhi).

But I am not sure if its the right time to visit the hills during rainy season. How are the roads to GHNP? Can a car be taken on the roads to GHNP during August?

Plus, is it safe to trek in August?

Comment: For the benefit of those like me who do not know, what is GHNP?

Comment: Google suggests that it is probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Himalayan_National_Park

Comment: [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25704/travelling-to-himalayan-national-park-or-nanda-devi-reserve-in-monsoon) question could be of help